# I am not understanding why my recursive function is not behaving as I expect

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I am trying to create a function that returns the position of the right most position of a given integer in an array. Example: [1,2,3,4,5,6] find right most position of 4 would return 4. [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6] find right most position of 4 would return 6.

I am trying to implement a recursive call in my function. When printing out the recursive call I see the correct position, though I am having trouble ultimately returning that number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int RightMostBinarySearch(int *arr, int length, int find, int i, int j) {
    int middle = (i + j) / 2; //This will be floor due to integer data type
    while(i <= j){ //While the start does not excede int size of last value in array
        if(arr[middle] < find){ //If middle element is less than what is being searched for
            i = middle + 1; //Obviously the element is not found and the element is greater than middle point => make i one element to the right
        }
        else if(arr[middle] == find){ //The middle position is where the element exists in the array
            printf("%d\n", RightMostBinarySearch(arr, length, find, middle + 1, j));
            return middle + 1;
        }
        else{ //This condition will be when arr[midd] > find
            j = middle - 1; // make j 1 element left of middle because find is less than arr[middle]
        }
        middle = (i + j) / 2; //if not found i or j changes, thus middle must also change.
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 12 }; //Sorted int array of size n
    int find = 4;
    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); // Determines the length by getting the full size of memory array uses and dividing by he size of first element memory size. Full memory / element memory = num elements = length
    int i = 0;
    int j = length - 1; // Length of array is n, last element is represented n - 1
    int location = RightMostBinarySearch(arr,length, find, i, j);
    printf("The location of the element is at position: %d\n", location);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", RightMostBinarySearch(arr, length, find, middle + 1, j));` It is always a red flag when the result of a recursive call is neither saved to a variable nor returned from the function. That is, what is the point of calling the function if the return value is effectively not used (apart from a debug print statement).

Comment: Assign the result of the recursive call to a variable. Then you can print the variable and also return it.

Comment: Just a note that some languages provide a method or function to provide the index directly. In Ruby, for example, `1 + [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6].rindex(4) #=> 6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function `RightMostBinarySearch` recurses, you print its return value but always return `middle + 1`, which might not even be an offset with the `find` value appears.

You should modify the function this way:

```
int RightMostBinarySearch(int *arr, int length, int find, int i, int j) {
    //While the start does not exceed int size of last value in array
    while (i <= j) {
        // This will be floor due to integer data type
        // Also avoid potential integer overflow in i+j
        // make sure the middle element is > i unless i == j
        int middle = i + (j - i + 1) / 2;
        //If middle element is less than what is being searched for
        if (arr[middle] < find) {
            //Obviously the element is not found and the element is greater than middle point => make i one element to the right
            i = middle + 1;
        } else
        if (arr[middle] == find) {
            //The middle position is where the element exists in the array
            if (middle == j) {
                /* middle is the last possible value */
                return middle;
            } else {
                return RightMostBinarySearch(arr, length, find, middle, j));
            }
        } else {
            //This condition will be when arr[midd] > find
            j = middle - 1; // make j 1 element left of middle because find is less than arr[middle]
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that this problem can be solved easily without a recursive function, with a simpler API:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int LeftMostBinarySearch(const int *arr, int length, int find) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = length;

    while (i < j) {
        // compute mid-point avoiding potential overflow on i+j
        int middle = i + (j - i) / 2;
        if (arr[middle] < find) {
            i = middle + 1;
        } else {
            j = middle;
        }
    }
    if (i < length && arr[i] == find)
        return i;
    else
        return -1;
}

int RightMostBinarySearch(const int *arr, int length, int find) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = length;

    while (i < j) {
        // compute mid-point avoiding potential overflow on i+j
        int middle = i + (j - i) / 2;
        if (arr[middle] <= find) {
            i = middle + 1;
        } else {
            j = middle;
        }
    }
    if (i > 0 && arr[i - 1] == find)
        return i - 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 12 }; //Sorted int array
    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); // Determines the length by getting the full size of memory array and dividing by the size of first element. Full memory / element memory = num elements = length
    int find = 4;
    int left_location = LeftMostBinarySearch(arr, length, find);
    int right_location = RightMostBinarySearch(arr, length, find);
    printf("The first element %d is at position: %d\n", find, left_location);
    printf("The last element %d is at position: %d\n", find, right_location);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am somewhat confused what "return (k < 0) ? middle : k;" exactly means. I have never used this yet. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `return (k < 0) ? middle : k;` uses the ternary operator available in many languages. This statement is equivalent to `if (k < 0) { return middle; } else { return k; }`. Answer updated.

Comment: @HaydenLabrie: I posted a better modification of your recursive function without this test and using tail recursion.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using recursion, I don't think you'd need the while loop?

Here is how I think you can arrive at the solution for this problem. You should return for every step as I see put.

```c
int rmst(int *arr, int length, int find, int i, int j){                         
    if (i <= j) {                                                               
        int middle = (i+j)/2;                                                   
        if (arr[middle] < find){                                                
            return rmst(arr, length, find, middle+1, j);                        
        } else if (arr[middle] == find){                                        
            if ((middle + 1) < length){                                         
                if (arr[middle + 1] == find){ // continue binary search if the next guy is still == find, otherwise, return middle.                                   
                    return rmst(arr, length,find, middle+1, j);                
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   
            return middle;                                                      
        } else {                                                                
            return rmst(arr, length, find, i, middle -1);                       
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    return -1;                                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly indices in arrays in C start from 0.

Secondly the value of the parameter `length` is not used in your function.

Thirdly if the first if condition evaluates to true then in fact you have not a recursive function. You have an iterative function with a while loop.

```
while(i <= j){ //While the start does not excede int size of last value in array
    if(arr[middle] < find){ //If middle element is less than what is being searched for
        i = middle + 1; //Obviously the element is not found and the element is greater than middle point => make i one element to the right
    }

    //...

    middle = (i + j) / 2; //if not found i or j changes, thus middle must also change.
}
```

So when the value of the variable `find` is greater than any element of the array you have a fully iterative function.

When this if statement

```
    else if(arr[middle] == find){ //The middle position is where the element exists in the array
        printf("%d\n", RightMostBinarySearch(arr, length, find, middle + 1, j));
        return middle + 1;
    }
```

evaluates to true then this call

```
RightMostBinarySearch(arr, length, find, middle + 1, j)
```

has no effect and the function returns the value of `middle + 1` independent on whether indeed `arr[middle + 1]` is equal to `find`.

The function has too many parameters.

And at last the parameter that specifiers the array shall have the qualifier `const` because the array itself is not being changed within the function.

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t RightMostBinarySearch( const int *a, size_t n, int value )
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( value < a[n / 2] )
    {
        return RightMostBinarySearch( a, n / 2, value );
    }
    else if ( a[n / 2] < value )
    {
        size_t result = RightMostBinarySearch( a + 1 + n / 2, n - 1 - n / 2, value );
        return result == -1 ? result : result + 1  + n / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t result = RightMostBinarySearch( a + 1 + n / 2, n - 1 - n / 2, value );
        return result == -1 ? n / 2 : result + 1 + n / 2;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );

    printf( "%zu\n", RightMostBinarySearch( a1, N1, 4 ) );

    int a2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6 };
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );

    printf( "%zu\n", RightMostBinarySearch( a2, N2, 4 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
3
5
```

As you can see neither while statement or any other loop is present in the recursive function.